# limit directory with GetOpenFileName()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I know that Microsoft recommends using the Common Item Dialog boxes over `GetOpenFileName()` and `GetSaveFileName()` but I am working with some older code.

How can I limit `GetOpenFileName()` to only allow the user to select files in a certain directory?

For example, I only want the user to be able to select a file from the "Images" directory. I don't want them to be able to navigate into other directories when opening a file. They must select a file from the "Images" directory.

The flag **OFN_NOCHANGEDIR** sounds like it could be what I need, but that just changes the current directory back to the original directory if the user changes it when opening a file.

If it's not possible with `GetOpenFileName()`, is it possible with the newer Common Item Dialog?

Comment: What do you want that restriction? User can at least copy file that he wants to open to your directory

Comment: @Lol4t0: I've seen apps do this to ensure that all the project files are in one directory. Yes you can copy into the directory but that's the point. Everything in one place where it is easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `GetOpenFileName()` and `GetSaveFileName()`, you can assign a callback procedure to the `OPENFILENAME::lpfnHook` field. When it receives a [`CDN_FILEOK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646857.aspx) notification, retrieve the selected folder by sending the dialog a [`CDM_GETFOLDERPATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646850.aspx) message.  If the folder is not acceptable to you, display a message to the user and then reject the selected file(s) by calling `SetWindowLong()` to set a nonzero `DWL_MSGRESULT` value, and return a nonzero value from the hook procedure.

**Update**: for `IFileOpenDialog` and `IFileSaveDialog`, you can implement the [`IFileDialogEvents::OnFolderChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775881.aspx) event callback to prevent navigation to unwanted folders, by simply returning an error `HRESULT` value other than `S_OK` or `E_NOTIMPL`.

Comment: Looks like there is no built-in functionality to do this and would need to manually handle it myself. Thanks for the tip.